# Go AWS, marshal to JSON from DynamoDB Item, omit null values

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to query my DynamoDB table and convert the results to a json string.

```
sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("eu-central-1")},
)
dyn = dynamodb.New(sess)

var limit int64 = 5
out, err := dyn.Scan(&dynamodb.ScanInput{
    TableName: aws.String("Products"),
    Limit: &limit,
})

b, _ := json.Marshal(out.Items[0])
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

But the result is unfortunately filled with NULLs, and I don't want to send the whole thing over the wire:

```
"Price":{"B":null,"BOOL":null,"BS":null,"L":null,"M":null,"N":"17119","N
S":null,"NULL":null,"S":null,"SS":null}
```

I know that this has to do with the dynamo.AttributeValue type.
Is it possible to omit null values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So I found "an" answer but I don't know if there's a better one.

```
var p Product
dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(out.Items[0], &p)
b, _ := json.Marshal(p)
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

First I unmarshal the item from DynamoDB to a Go Struct then marshal to JSON.
That seems like a lot of work, I would prefer to go from `map[string]*AttributeValue` directly to a JSON string (without all these `NULL` values of course)

So if somebody can come up with something more elegant, pls share.

Comment: import this at the top: import("github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"). Also if you have free form data you can "set var p interface{}"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with JSON struct omitempty tags

```
type Total struct {
    A *ColorGroup`json:",omitempty"`
    B string`json:",omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the type is part of the aws sdk, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/dynamodb/api.go#L3539

Comment: Right, but don't you create a dynamo attribute item at some point?  dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(item)

Comment: I'm basing my answer off of this:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/dynamo-example-create-table-item.html

Comment: It is irrelevant how the data inside the DynamoDB table is created. I have a JSON annotated Product struct, but that doesn't help here, because the problem seems to be with the dynamo.AttributeValue type. I have to first Unmarshal the AttributeValues and then Marshal to JSON: check my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit NULL values during marshaling by adding omitempty like this

```
type Person struct {
    Name    string
    Email   string   `dynamodbav:",omitempty"`
    Friends []string `dynamodbav:",omitemptyelem"`
}
```

godocs [type Encoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#Encoder)

Comment: does this eliminate the null values read from the db when it responds to `dyn.Scan` ? Or does it only eliminate null values at write ?

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly what you ask for, but it can help you to convert a map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue to string without null fields.

Surely exists a better way to do this, but this is how I rapidly solve my problem with Dynamo AttributeValues nulls for now.

I hope this can help you

```
func GetDynamoAttributeString(newImage dto.Transaction) string {
   newImageDynamoItem, _ := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(newImage)
   newImageBytesItem, _ := json.Marshal(newImageDynamoItem)

   var newImageItemMap map[string]interface{}

   _ = json.Unmarshal(newImageBytesItem, &newImageItemMap)
   removeNulls(newImageItemMap)

   newImageStringItem, _ := json.Marshal(newImageItemMap)

   return string(newImageStringItem)
}

func removeNulls(m map[string]interface{}) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(m)
    for _, e := range val.MapKeys() {
        v := val.MapIndex(e)
        if v.IsNil() {
            delete(m, e.String())
            continue
        }
        switch t := v.Interface().(type) {
        // If key is a JSON object (Go Map), use recursion to go deeper
        case map[string]interface{}:
            removeNulls(t)
        }
    }
}
```

Reference to remove null fields on golang maps: https://www.ribice.ba/golang-null-values/